# Make it possible to search for questions and answer for a particular user

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, users

Would be very handy if I could search for questions and answers by a particular user. Especially my own user. So that I could more easily find questions I have asked a long time ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Already possible via the search keyword, which will do exactly what you're requesting

```
user:<userid> 
user:39321
```

A list of all the functionality is available [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search).

Comment: +1 Same answer. Damn I edit and read way to slow.

Comment: Perfect      =)

Comment: And for your own: `user:me`

Answer (score 1):

This is already possible. See the FAQ [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search)

Expansion:

You can search for a specific user by using the keyword user and the user id.

```
user:[userid]
```