# Searching for a particular user's questions

Tags: support, questions, search, users

I wanted to search for posts by a particular user. I'm not sure of the syntax, or if there is a specific search syntax for this.

How is search made on user questions specific?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12795/make-it-possible-to-search-for-questions-and-answer-for-a-particular-user http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/how-do-you-search-by-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search -- this is linked on every search result page in the right hand column as well.

Answer (score 7):

For eg, Search [`user:138350 pagination`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:138350+pagination)

Answer (score 4):

You can search user questions from the search bar, just input `user:130154` to see my questions here on Meta. You can get your own questions by searching `user:me`.